# Change colours when "safely removing" devices

Tags: windows-11

I used the "safely remove hardware" option from the system tray and was confronted with this:

[image: safely remove hardware]

So easy to read the dark grey against the black!

Any clues about how to adjust the colours?

Comment: I get that it's a bit dark, but it's perfectly legible. is your display correctly calibrated? [Because of the 'magic' of colour profiles, we cannot see what you see, even when we're looking at the exact same picture posted online. Display profiling can make *all* the difference. Most laptops are sold with the displays set 'over-punchy' to make them look good on the shop floor… this is not good for the eventual owner, only the shop.]

Comment: You are aware that due to changes behind the scenes, for the most part, it's unnecessary to "safety remove" storage devices on Windows 10+?

Comment: @Tetsujin Display is correctly calibrated. Machine is a desktop with a 43" monitor. Yes, it's barely legible to me ( I have substantially "experienced" eyes) though the graphic posted is far larger than the actual pop-up. Theoretically simple thing to do to adjust the grey font to a nice sky blue or lemon yellow. It's turning the theory to practice that's the stumbling block.

Comment: @Ramhound : First I've ever heard that "safely remove" is no longer necessary...!

Comment: @Ramhound, though many USB flash drives default as "removable media", that is **not** true for external HDD drives, which might have cached writes awaiting finalization.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I would have to go back and find the articles I read 5-6 years ago, I am not entirely sure, what I read made the differences known.  You certainly don't want to eject any storage device while it's being written to, but with the way Windows now handles the cache, what I read indicate it might not be strickly require to eject the device.